# Should Artifactory API Keys be disclosed?

Tags: security, artifactory, api-key

I have git cloned a repository and I have noticed a developer has set an artifactory authentication API key in a gradle.build file, along with his own username.
Is this a security issue? If this file is leaked, a hacker would be able to download the dependencies? Should I ask him to revoke the API Key?
(it would be nice if you add references supporting your answering statement)

Comment: If the repository is public, and the api key is a read-only key, there is no issue with that

Comment: Does it grant access to something which someone else should not have access to? Is the key used to collect some sort of metrics and attributing them back to a particular user or use case for follow-up or even budgeting?

Comment: @tripleee yes, the developer put in order to download dependencies developed by other developers in the company

Comment: Then if you want to prevent that the answer is obviously yes.

Answer (score 2):

It's never a good idea to publicly share a password or an API key, especially for private accounts that may have additional permissions added in the future.

If you need to grant users an option to access specific repository/resource and don't want to enable anonymous access you can use [transient users](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/support-authentication-for-non-existing-users)